# Can't get <label> and <input> on the same line

Tags: html, css, input, formatting, label

I can't seem to get <label> and <input> on the same line under "Schedule preferences". [CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/Mike-Jewett/pen/ZEPOVjR)

I've tried floating and table cell attribute manipulation. Any help would be greatly appreciated as something this simple shouldn't be giving me such a difficult time.

```
    <label for="schedule-preference">Schedule Preferences:</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="weekday" name="schedule_preference" value="weekday">
    <label for="weekday">Weekday</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="weekday_evenings" name="schedule_preference" value="weekday_evenings">
    <label for="weekday_evenings">Weekday evenings</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="weekend" name="schedule_preference" value="weekend">
    <label for="weekend">Weekend</label><br>
```

Comment: Instead of linking to a CodePen, edit your question to use a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). CodePen links go dead over time, and the goal of StackOverflow is to be a repository of helpful questions and answers that users can reference into the future.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because your labels are all styled with either `display: table-cell` or `display: block`. For the labels you want to appear beside their inputs, you'll need to style them as `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.